# Why can't Pinterest fetch images from sites with SNI based SSLs?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pinterest, sni

Adding SSLs to our domains creates an image fetching error and doesn't allow the image to be Pinned though the images work fine for Facebook, Twitter, Google+, LinkedIn, Instagram, etc.

I'm running AWS EC2 instances with a standalone RDS database server and I am not presently hosting the images on S3, nor do I have Cloudfront distributions for the site or any buckets or any caching plugins that would interfere. The site in question is a clean Wordpress install on a new domain where we are migrating several other sites to. Prior to the addition of the SSL, images were fetched and Pins created without issue.

[Pinterest also runs on AWS EC2 instances](http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/case-studies/pinterest/).

[Pinterest also runs SSL](https://snar.ly/x/34_Pinterest_Discover_and_save_creative_ideas_2015-06-01_13-46-56.png).

So, we have a secure connection on the same host.

How do I make it so my website visitors can Pin to Pinterest?

[The solution listed here doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946537/image-fetch-issues-in-pinterest-and-twitter-from-amazon-cloudfront)

As a temporary workaround, we've re-routed the domain at [Wendy Polisi](https://wendypolisi.com) to use an alias with an AWS Elastic Load Balancer which fools the Pinterest script into allowing the image to be fetched and the Pin to be registered, but this has been fraught with its own debacles. There have been 3 node failures in the last week alone causing the site to display chronic intermittent WSOD and requiring us to notify AWS so they can replace the node so we're going to eliminate this as a "solution".

Comment: @kent-brewster

http://stackoverflow.com/users/1151280/kent-brewster

I'd really appreciate some help here.

Comment: This questions is a duplicate of [Image Fetch issues in Pinterest and Twitter from Amazon CloudFront](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946537/image-fetch-issues-in-pinterest-and-twitter-from-amazon-cloudfront). Apart from that it only complains and this forum is probably not a suitable way for contacting Pinterest.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich while I appreciate your point of view, it's not a duplicate of that question because we haven't enabled Cloudfront to serve the images yet as this is a new domain we're migrating sites to and adding Cloudfront and caching adds yet another layer of complexity and problems that then have to be deciphered. 

There's no complaint anywhere in my post, simply an explanation of the path, the problem and a request for a solution. 

With respect to it not being a suitable way to contact Pinterest, the lead engineer is on here answering questions so I don't get your point.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that this site is the normal way for getting support for Pinterest. But I actually don't see anything in your question which is related to [the topics of this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), i.e. you don't ask for a programming problem you have but ask why Pinterest does not solve their programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if Pinterest is using SSL, or if it uses AWS or anything like this. Using the SNI extension for accessing a URL is a client side issue and while all modern browsers use SNI lots of other tools do not. For example python just recently added support in 2.7.9 (but it was for a while in 3.x), Apache HTTPClient as shipped with Android SDK has not SNI support etc.

And SNI or not has also nothing to do with using a certificate from Comodo or some other CA, but is completely independent of the issuer of the certificate. The only question is if you have multiple certificates behind the same IP address because in this case you need to use SNI on the server side (and on the client side too of course).

> Pinterest also runs on AWS EC2 instances.
>
> Pinterest also runs SSL.
>
> So, we have a secure connection on the same host.

It would be an unlikely coincidence if Pinterest would actually run on the same host as your site. AWS EC2 has definitely way more than a single host.

I agree with you that if Pinterest has SNI problems then these should be fixed as soon as possible, because more and more sites (like all of Cloudfront Free SSL) use SNI. In the mean time you could try to switch your HTTPS site to a dedicated IP address so that you don't depend on SNI.

Comment: I've rephrased the post. Yes, there are several dozen domains hosted on this webserver with the same Elastic IP Address. 

With respect to why I asked a Pinterest related question, it's because of the prior post you referenced which has a similar issue and because the lead engineer said in that post that Pinterest is listening as you can see here: 

https://snar.ly/pinterest

Yes, I realize that we're on different instances with different IP ranges. My point was that we're with the same provider and not running incompatible technology.

So, what's the solution?

Comment: I don't see a solution except not relying on SNI.  Yes it will cost you some more but at the end you are getting something back for it.

Comment: As I indicated, moving it to an Elastic Load Balancer with an alias (different IP) enabled images to be fetched but we're experiencing chronic and repetitive node failures causing intermittent WSOD which is obviously less than ideal for revenue generation and visitor satisfaction. Hence, the question asked above. 

Surely, there's another solution?

Comment: If you care about revenue you might share some of it with Pinterest so that they are more motivated to fix the issue.  Apart from that you might try to find out and fix the underlying problem of the node failures or just move to a more stable platform with a dedicated IP. And of course you could still fall back to HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: I realize you think you're a comedian, but the reason we have hundreds of thousands of Pins is because we do pay to play with Facebook and Pinterest. Unlike many of the self entitled people on the Internet who think everything should be free, we realize that they aren't philanthropies. 

Unfortunately, despite paying, Pinterest support has a 3 business day response time which then generally doesn't create a solution.

When you say, "fallback to HTTP", are you referring to stripping the SSL certificate from Apache and reverting back to a non-SSL domain or some other workaround?

Comment: It's a pity that Pinterest is not able to properly deal with this issue, even for paying customers. But until they fix this problem you can only move away from SNI either by having a dedicated IP (on a stable system) or by moving back to HTTP instead of HTTPS. And yes, this probably means to disable SSL from Apache completely. In theory you might offer both HTTP and HTTPS in parallel but then you can not control if your users try to pin the HTTP or HTTPS version and thus you will still have (less) problems.